# Match through nested function

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have this sample:

[image]

I expect `arg3` to be colored green as `arg1`, `arg2` and `FunCall` with my current setting:

```
syn match pyFun "xxxx" contains=xxx
syn region pyFunCall start="(" end=")" contained contains=xxxx transparent keepend
syn match pyFunCallParams "xxx" contained contains=xxxx skipwhite
syn match pyFunCallParam "xxx" contained contains=xxx skipwhite
```

I guess with the above, a match starts with `(` from `myFunc` then it matches `)` of `FunCall` and ends the region, so `arg3` is actually out of match and I can't highlight it.

My question is how can I ignore `()` inside my pyFunCall, I appended `transparent` but it didn't work.

Comment: The code in the question does not produce the result in the screenshot: it looks like you've attempted to cut it down to the part that you think causes the issue, but it would be easier to write/test an answer if you provide *functional* sample code.

Comment: @Rich: thanks for reply. I've found the answer, just exclude ) in pyFunCall.

Comment: Glad you've got something working. It doesn't sound like the best solution, but, again, hard to tell without the actual code!